# .Net Salesforce integration - getting column values from List<sObject>

Tags: .net, salesforce, integration

We are using the Partner API in our .Net integration with Salesforce.com. I am using the following code to add Account records to a dictionary using the ExternalId__c as the key for each record.

```
public Dictionary<string, List<sObject>> getAccountMap(SalesforceConnection clientConn)
{
    Dictionary<string, List<sObject>> accountByMerchNum = new Dictionary<string, List<sObject>>();

    List<sObject> sObjRTypes = clientConn.performQuery("SELECT Id, ExternalId__c FROM Account");

    if (sObjRTypes != null && sObjRTypes.Count > 0)
    {
        sObject Account = sObjRTypes[0];
        foreach (XmlElement elem in Account.Any)
        {
            if (elem.LocalName.ToString() == "ExternalId__c")
            {
                if (accountByMerchNum.ContainsKey(elem.InnerText))
                {
                    accountByMerchNum[elem.InnerText].Add(Account);
                }
                else
                {
                    accountByMerchNum.Add(elem.InnerText, new List<sObject> { Account });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return accountByMerchNum;
}
```

How do I pull out specific column values from Dictionary>? Ive guessed that it should be something similar to the following...but my guesses have been incorrect so far.

```
Dictionary<string, List<sObject>> accountDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<sObject>>();
String tempId = accountDictionary[externalId].getId();
```

What is the correct syntax for pulling out specific column values from this type of collection?

Comment: Any special reason you need to use Partner API? If it doesn't have to work with several different Salesforce orgs it might be much simpler to use the enterprise version. Parsing (consuming) the WSDL would give you classes like Account or Contact with concrete fields, much simpler to use.

Comment: We're using Partner because of the amount of data thats being processed.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of ambiguous things in your code -

1. You are querying for all Account objects and processing only the first.If you are 
   interested in only certain objects why not provide a predicate (WHERE clause)in the query?
2. Your dictionary value is a `List<sObject>`. If `'ExternalId__c'` is a custom field which is unique you will always have a single Account object for each 'ExternalId__c' value. Maybe the dictionary should be string -> sObject. You can then access the dictionary value and call sObject methods on it. dict[externalId].getId() etc.